# How to write a dynamic Lambda Expression to access Nth Parent entity?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, lambda

I have an application using nhibernate and linq to do my queries on database. Everything works fine but I have the follow model mapped (with auto-related):

```
public class A
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; } 
    public virtual A ParentA { get; set; }  
}
```

I have a method to proccess some information and this method take a `count` integer parameter. 
I would like to know if is there any way to access the `count` times the ParentA property to create a filter.

```
protected void Proccess(int count, int id)
{
    var query = session.Query<A>();

    // I would like to access, the number of count variable in parentA property, something like:
    // for sample: if count is 3, I would like a query like: 
    query.Where(x => x.ParentA.ParentA.ParentA.Id == id);

    // maybe something like this:
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        query.Where(x => x.ParentA.ParentA.ParentA.Id == id);   
    }

    var result = query.ToList();

    // continue method...
}
```

Is there any way to create this kind of Lambda Expression?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking here, unfortunately.

Comment: I believe it is possible, but not the simplest thing. You would need to dynamically build expression tree for the where predicate. take a look here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
protected void Process(int count, int id)
{
    var query = session.Query<A>().Where(BuildFilter(count,id));
    var result = query.ToList();
}

private static Expression<Func<A, bool>> BuildFilter(int count, int id)
{
   var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(A), "x");

   Expression instance = x;
   if (count != 0)
   {
      var prop = typeof(A).GetProperty("ParentA");
      while (count > 0)
      {
         instance = Expression.Property(instance, prop);
         count--;
      }
   }

   var instanceId = Expression.Property(instance, "Id");
   var compareId = Expression.Constant(id);
   var body = Expression.Equal(instanceId, compareId);

   return Expression.Lambda<Func<A, bool>>(body, x);
}
```

Comment: I personally prefer to use a `LambdaExpression` instead of `Type.GetProperty`. The downside of course is you need to do some funky business with `ExpressionVisitor`.

Comment: Thank you guys, it works perfectly! Is there any material about expression you can recommend?

Comment: @FelipeOriani: [MSDN is a good place to start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The generated SQL will be no where near as "nice" as Richard Deeming's answer, but this has the advantage of being readable by those who don't know the `System.Linq.Expression` namespace.

```
protected List<A> Proccess(int count, int id)
{
    var query = session.Query<A>()
              .Select(x => new Pair { Item = x, Ancestor = x };  
    Func<IQueryable<Pair>, IQueryable<Pair>> addNesting 
              = q.Select(x => new Pair{ Item = x.Item, Ancestor = Ancestor.Parent });
    foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(0, count))
    {
        query = addNesting(query);
    }


    return query.Where(x => x.Ancestor == id).Select(x => x.Item).ToList();
}

private class Pair
{
   public A Item {get;set;}
   public A Ancestor { get; set; }
}
```